# Convert a Int to string

Tags: python

I am trying to convert an int to string but .astype and str are not working. I would like why and how to solve that.

Thanks

```
x=1303447996143673344
type(x)

#I trying with:

x.astype(str)
str(x)
```

the error that report google colab is TypeError: 'str' object is not callable. However in jupyter works without problem the .astype and str

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? `str(x)` certainly works for me.

Comment: Please provide errors that you are seeing so that we can provide better feedback

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-365-45314fa85f05> in <module>()
      2 type(x)
      3 
----> 4 str(x)

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: I am using google colabs

Comment: please post all errors in your post, not as a comment.

Comment: have you somehow overwritten ```str```?   getting ```TypeError: 'str' object is not callable``` certainly implies that.

Comment: Have you defined a variable called `str`? That might be why you're getting your error. Otherwise, `str(x)` should work fine.

Comment: The problem only happened in google colab. However in jupyternotebook works well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You aren’t defining `x` to be a string, and just calling it. Do `x = str(x)`.

Comment: Maybe explain what your code does for the OP? I'm reading it myself and don't understand why or how that helps/answers the problem

Comment: How does this have anything to do with the `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` error?

Comment: I tried with Jupyter notebook in anaconda and str(x) and I do not have problems. I do not know what happened with colabs. Thanks

Comment: Steal answers much? This was and is my answer before it was yours. You told him to use an f string if functions weren't working for some reason.

Comment: I realised he forgot to define x after looking at your answer. However, you do not need to define a new variable. The question states "I am trying to convert an int to string".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you aren't storing the return. You can't just dump an `int` into `str` and magically expect the `int` to be a `str`. Case in point, what if you did this: `str(10)`. Would you expect the number 10 to be a `str` for the rest of your program?

`a = str(x)`

`a` is now a `str` of `x`.
`x` is still an  `int`.

Comment: I tried with Jupyter notebook in anaconda and str(x) and I do not have problems. I do not know what happened with colabs. Thanks